# ADB logcat Google Play Store apps

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, logcat, cyanogenmod

On my Samsung Galaxy S2 with Cyanogenmod 13 it is possible to get logs from apps that I have installed from the Google Play Store. However, with my Nexus 5X Stock Android 6.0 I can get only logs from apps that I have started in Android studio. It is possible to get  also logs from apps that I have installed from the Google Play Store with my Nexus 5X Stock Android 6.0?

If I open "Select debug app" in the developer options, I see all apps on the Cyanogenmod 13 device, but only apps that was started by Android studio on the Nexus 5X.

Android studio is running on Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Perhaps CM 13 has a security flaw. Android locked down access to logs back with Android 4.1, a few years ago. Beyond that... what is your question?

Comment: I have read that Android locked down the access to logs, but only for third-party apps not for adb logcat respectively the integration of adb logcat in Android studio. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I misinterpreted your question -- sorry! I do not know why you would be unable to view logs on the 5X, assuming that `adb` is working in general with it (e.g., you have the right drivers on Windows). I just plugged my 5X in and confirmed that I am seeing messages from a variety of apps on the device.

Comment: I have forgotten to add that I use Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. Ubuntu and the 5X generally get along (other than USB tethering...). Are you sure that you have all the filters turned off in the Android Monitor?

Comment: I have turned off all filters. I think the problem is, that "If I open "Select debug app" in the developer options, I see all apps on the Cyanogenmod 13 device, but only apps that was started by Android studio on the Nexus 5X."

Comment: I have never used that option (other than just looking at it now, on a 6P and a 5X). That being said, given the behavior on stock Android, my guess is that it is supposed to only show apps that are marked as debuggable. On an emulator, that would be everything. On production hardware, that's supposed to only be those built with `debuggable` set to `true` (by default: `debug` builds). Perhaps CM 13 has an option to make everything appear to be debuggable.

Comment: I just fired up a 7.0 emulator, and "Select debug app" shows all processes. So, I stand by my theory that this is supposed to show debuggable apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't saw any play store app in my emulator to install app from it , so how can I get logs of them

Comment: @UmarAta: Again, *logs* show up in LogCat. What the OP is complaining about is "Select debug app" in Settings > Developer options (and, frankly, I don't even know what that does).